# Explicitly unwrapping optional nil does not cause crash

Tags: swift

A few folks asked this question before, yet no answer was accepted.

I have a `UITableViewCell` that contains a `UITextField`.

If I click slightly outside of the textField the row highlights. I want to prevent this.

To prevent it I do the following:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath! {
    return nil
}
```

This works perfectly fine.  Here is my question.  The author of the tutorial states:

> Note that returning nil from a method is only allowed if there is a
>   question mark (or exclamation point) behind the return type.

What does he mean that you can put an exclamation mark behind the optional return type?  Why doesn't the program crash?  Returning nil after I place an exclamation mark after the IndexPath return type doesn't crash.  I thought `!` would explicitly unwrap the nil and fail?

Comment: That delegate method should return `IndexPath?` (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614943-tableview), why did you make the return type an implicitly unwrapped optional? Btw, Xcode issues a warning *"Overriding instance method optional result type 'IndexPath?' with implicitly unwrapped optional type 'IndexPath!'"*

Comment: The quote is correct. You can return `nil` if the return type is `IndexPath!` or `IndexPath?`

Comment: @MartinR.  I'm trying to understand why the author stated: returning nil from a method is only allowed if there is a question mark (or exclamation point) behind the return type.

I thought if you place an exclamation point behind an optional that is nil the program would crash.

Comment: You can have an implicitly unwrapped optional with a nil value, it would only crash once you attempt to use it in a way that requires it to be unwrapped.

Comment: Now it makes sense.  Thanks Dan!

Comment: It surprises me that the compiler lets you define a function with a different return type (`IndexPath!` vs. `IndexPath?`) and it still maps it to the protocol method. Usually in Swift if the function result is different, it treats it as a different function.

Comment: @DuncanC: Perhaps because “Implicitly unwrapped optional” is not a separate type anymore, compare https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md.

Comment: Yeah, I discovered that the type wasn't distinct any more after posting my comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Swift 3, “Implicitly unwrapped optional” is not a separate type,
but an *attribute* on the declaration of a regular/strong optional.
For the details, see [SE-0054 Abolish ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional type](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md).

A function with an IUO return type can return `nil`,
and assigning the return value to a variable makes that a regular
optional:

```
func foo() -> Int! {
    return nil
}

let x = foo() // Type of `x` is `Int?`
print(x) // nil
```

Only if evaluation as an optional is not possible then the value
will be forced-unwrapped (and cause a runtime exception is the
value is `nil`):

```
let y = 1 + foo() // Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

In your case, your

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath!
```

method overrides the `UITableViewController` method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath?
```

and can return `nil`. This does not crash unless the caller unwraps
the value.

---

*Remark:* The above is meant as an explanation why your code compiles
and works. Generally, I do not see a good reason to use implicitly
unwrapped optional return types. The main use-cases of IUOs are
stated in SE-0054:

> The ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional ("IUO") type is a valuable tool for importing Objective-C APIs where the nullability of a parameter or return type is unspecified. It also represents a convenient mechanism for working through definite initialization problems in initializers.

Answer (score 1):

One way to think this as a choise of the API Implementor. If implementor handles the input arguments it will not be any problem to the API User.

Lets create a drawing text class which just prints at console.

```
class TextDrawer {

  var mustBeText: String!

  func renderText(string: String) {
      print(string)
  }

  func renderSafely() {
     renderText(string: self.mustBeText ?? "Nothing found to be rendered")
     // or 
     if let safeString = self.mustBeText {
        renderText(string: safeString)
     }
  }

  func renderUnsafely() {
      renderText(string: mustBeText)
  }
}
```

We have defined the `mustBeText` as `String!` means we are allowed to expect any string as well as `nil` argument.

Now, as we create a instance of the class as below:

```
let textDrawer = TextDrawer()
textDrawer.mustBeText = nil // this is allowed since the `mustBeText` is `String!`.

textDrawer.renderSafely() // prints -- Nothing found to be rendered

textDrawer.renderUnsafely() // crashes at runtime.
```

The `renderUnsafaly()` will crash since its not handling the `nil` case.