# Why does a `nil` implicitly unwrapped optional print `nil` and not crash?

Tags: swift

I have an implicitly unwrapped optional with value `nil`.

Why does it print `nil` and  not crash?

```
var x : Int!
print(x) // nil
```

Comment: it should... if thats what you have done... show your code

Comment: Compare e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49559821/explicitly-unwrapping-optional-nil-does-not-cause-crash. – An IUO is only force-unwrapped if required by the type checker, otherwise it behaves like a regular optional.

Comment: `var x: Int?
print(x!)`

Comment: could you clarify

Comment: because when you use ! for unwrapped you tell Xcode I'm sure I fill it before I wanna use it

Comment: Note that your code produces the warning "Expression implicitly coerced from 'Int?' to 'Any'", and [this warning will soon be improved](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/23617) to "coercion of implicitly unwrappable value of type 'Int?' to 'Any' does not unwrap optional" for IUOs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That does not crash because `print` accepts `Any` as the first parameter. Are implicitly unwrapped optionals a kind of `Any`? Yes they are! Anything is `Any`. There is no need to unwrap the optional. An implicitly unwrapped optional can be used in a place where `Any` is expected without unwrapping the optional.

That could potentially be confusing because now you have something with type `Any`, which doesn't look like it's optional, but it is an optional under the hood. To avoid this, Swift will output a warning telling you  that you are implicitly coercing whatever optional type to `Any`.

You need to use `!` to force unwrap it here:

```
print(x!)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's not crashing is because you are not *force-unwrapping* it in `print(x)`. It will only crash one you try to force-unwrap it like `print(x!)`

IUO(Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals) are just special type of Optionals which will be automatically unwrapped one you use it inside chaining (say optional chaining), otherwise they remain Optionals.

Consider an example:

```
var implicitlyUO: Int!
implictlyUO = 4

print(implicitlyUO) // prints Optional(4)
print(implicitlyUO.advanced(by: 3)) // prints 7

implicitlyUO = nil

print(implicitlyUO) // prints nil
print(implicitlyUO.advanced(by: 3)) // Here it will crash as now it will be unwrapped and found it nil

var someNilValue:Int?
someNilValue = 4

print(someNilValue) // prints Optional(4)
print(someNilValue?.advanced(by: 3)) // prints Optional(7)

someNilValue = nil

print(someNilValue) // prints nil
print(someNilValue?.advanced(by: 3)) // prints nil
print(someNilValue!.advanced(by: 3)) /* Will crash here as we are force unwrapping nil which is the same case as implicitlyUO */
```

The only advantage you get with IUO is that you don't need `!` (or explicitly unwrapping) in your code unnecessarily but you need to make sure that it is not nil.

Comment: it is supposed to crash not to print "nil" because it is " implicitly unwrapped optional "

Comment: @HaithamGado updated my answer, please check